# Obtaining Day Count Until Local User Password Expiration in Linux Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am using RHEL 6.9.

How may I obtain, in a Bash script, the count of days until the expiration of a local user's password?

I have tried:

```
chage -l <username>
passwd -S <username>
```

Neither of these provides a direct answer.

The former provides an expiration date string formatted like "Sep 29, 2019".

The latter provides a date string, representing the date the password was last set (formatted as above), and it also provides the number of days the password is valid.

With difficult parsing (well, difficult in a Bash script), either could be used to derive the number of days until password expiration. I am hoping there is a way to get the number of days until password expiration directly.

Does anybody in the community know how I may do this?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I am hoping there is a way to get the number of days until password expiration directly.

This has to be scripted. The following script should get you started:

```
#! /bin/bash

# get password data in array
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
chagedata=( $(LC_TIME=C chage -l $USER | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d " " -f 2-) )   
IFS=$saveIFS

# obtain times in seconds
now=$(date +%s)
expires=$(date +%s -d "${chagedata[1]}")

# compute days left (roughly...)
daysleft=$(( ($expires-$now)/(3600*24) ))
echo "Days left: $daysleft"
```

Source: [bash - Formatting chage command date output - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063545/formatting-chage-command-date-output), question by [Roman Rdgz](https://askubuntu.com/users/93023/roman-rdgz), answer by [danzel](https://askubuntu.com/users/354663/danzel).

Comment: This works except for the case of needing to check if chagedata[1] == "never". Thank you!